# Superscipt and Subscript buttons on TinyMCE

Tags: html, angularjs, tinymce

Hey super simple question. Is there a way to add the superscipt and subscript buttons to the TinyMCE editor. I'm currently using it with AngularJS and so my current formatting is like this:

```
<textarea
    ng-model="myModel"
    options='{
        "type":"tinymce",
        "config":{
        "plugins":["lists link image charmap print media save table template paste imagetools toc"],
        "toolbar":"undo redo bold italic underline bullist link charmap"                        
        }
    }'>
</textarea>
```

with a directive that handles everything. I know that I can get superscript and subscript in the menubar under the "Format" dropdown menu. But i need it as buttons.

This is the angular wrapper I'm using for tinyMCE: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `superscript` and `subscript` to your toolbar.  For example:

```
toolbar: [
    "superscript subscript...",
    "undo redo bold..."
],
```